# Determine type in return Enumerable.Range()

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Trying to understand what data type returns `Enumerable.Range()` function in sample below:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000000);
Console.WriteLine( numbers.GetType().FullName );
```

According to description it should return `IEnumerable<int>`. But according to my understanding this is just interface and returned object class should implement this interface. What is that object?

Console output brings

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<RangeIterator>d__113
```

I can't figure out what type I can place instead of `var` in my code line. I can't find `RangeIterator` type at all in MSDN. Waht does `d__113` means in this output?

Comment: `I can't figure out what type I can place instead of var in my code line.` Why do you need or want to? `IEnumerable<int>` will work, but again, why do you care?

Comment: You should use the interface as that’s what’s returned. Why do you need the concrete implementation, which is private anyway? Even if it wasn’t private what would be the benefit to typecast it to the concrete type which would just introduce the potential error of breaking your code when the interface implementation changes in the future.

Comment: Rather than thinking of it as a concrete type, you can think of it as a stream of numbers that come through when you iterate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you review the source of the code in question it sould shed some light as to what is actually happening

Source [Enumerable.Range](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1265)

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int count) {
    long max = ((long)start) + count - 1;
    if (count < 0 || max > Int32.MaxValue) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("count");
    return RangeIterator(start, count);
}

static IEnumerable<int> RangeIterator(int start, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) yield return start + i;
}
```

> I can't figure out what type I can place instead of `var` in my code line

Just use `IEnumerable<int>`

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000000);
```